# Erro script Analytics Google

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

Olá, estou tendo um erro no script gerado pelo Google do Analytics. Que está exatamente desta forma:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX-X"></script>

    <script>

      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

      gtag('js', new Date());        

      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X');

    </script>
```

No console do navegador aparece o seguinte:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;                (index):12

Essa linha 12 é exatamente essa:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

Eu não consigo entender o motivo deste erro, visto que estou copiando o que o Google me forneceu, colei no inicio da tag `<head>`conforme especificado pelo Google.

Comment: Dá uma olhada direito, porque estou achando que o erro não é nessa linha, até porque não há nenhum erro nela.

Comment: Eu também acho que seja isso, só que esse script é o primeiro  carregar no head, tipo não tem nada antes que possa estar dando pau.

Answer (score 0):

Tente com este Codigo:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-ID-ANALITCS', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Já testei com essa tag, mas dá erro também.